# Insert mongodb document at specific time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to know if there’s a way to insert Data in database in a specific moment,

Exemple:
I want to send a text to the Database in 3 hours => As soon as i click on my button in my client side i want the document to be created in 3 hours.

Is it possible to do something like this ?

Comment: Yes, possible. You just wait 3 hours (using whatever method you choose) and create then. Alternatively, you can create it _now_, and only act on it 3 hours later.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use setTimeOut like this.

```
let time = 60000 * 60 * 3;
function myFunc(arg) {
  console.log(`arg was => ${arg}`);
}

setTimeout(myFunc, time, 'funky');
```

or use cronjob like this npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good way to create documents. I don't know your problem, but I would solve it differently.

You could create the document when the button is clicked. **But**, you'll add a new property in your document like `active_at` that will hold a date value (timestamp or other). This value will be always `current date + 3 hours`. In your application, after that, you'll have to select/get documents where `active_at` is before the current date. This way, you'll have only the documents created at least 3 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` function in nodejs backend:

```
function myFunc(arg) {
  //Insert text to mongodb
}
setTimeout(myFunc, 10800000); //myFunc will be called after 3 hours (10.8000.000 ms)
```

You can find more detail about setTimeout function here: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args

Comment: Yeah, do that and pray your server lives long enough :)